# Instagram graph api permissions

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to prototype a "Hashtag Search" app. But it seems like to get access to the Instagrem Hashtag api from the graph API, I need instagram_basic access and to get that permission I need to go through an app review . One of the requirement of app review is a working app and a whole set of information like verified business account.

It looks like a loop of requirements to me, or I am missing something. Even graph explorer gives the same permission response.

I need "app review" access to create the "prototype app" in dev mode, and I need "app review" for the "app prototype".

Any advice on how to approach this?

I have an my app is in development mode and yes I have an access token.